# Changing the .Xauthority file path generated by server when a client tries to `ssh -Y` to it

Tags: linux, ssh, x11

Hi fellow stackoverflowers,

This are the relavant variable that was changed in the server.

```
# ~/.zshrc

`export XAUTHORITY="$XDG_CACHE_HOME"/Xauthority`
```

```
# /etc/sddm.conf

[X11]
UserAuthFile=.cache/Xauthority
```

(wanted to put it in `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`) but can't get it to work with sddm as the sddm `$UserAuthFile` variable is a relative path from ~ directory and appending .. does'nt help so I sticked with `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`

So now my issue is when I try to `ssh -Y` into the server. The `.Xauthority` file is always generated in the home directory while xauth is try to read from the `$XAUTHORITY` directory.

Thus resulting in the following error whenever I try to `ssh -Y` from a client

`X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.`

Which can be resolved by:

`mv ~/.Xauthority $XDG_CACHE_HOME/Xauthority`

How can I specify the location of the Xauthority file generated when X11 forwarding